# Generating types from object type descriptions

Tags: typescript

There are many cases where object type descriptors are needed (automatic UI for something like storybook). I can't seem to find a simple way to turn those into Types.

Example:

```
const buttonProps = {
 name: {kind:"string", empty:false},
 height: {kind:"number", min:20, max:50},
 width: {kind:"number", min:80},
 dark: {kind:"boolean"}
}
```

And I want back a type:

```
interface ButtonProps {
 name:string;
 height: number;
 width: number;
 dark: boolean;
}
```

But I am stuck. Once you start manipulations with typeof you lose the values to work off of. Best I could do is replace kind:"number" with number:true since then it is a prop name, but I don't like that (it works with number:false as well).

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You lose the actual "values" because the object isn't immutable, so TypeScript infers `string` (for instance) for `kind` rather than the string literal types `"string"`, `"number"`, or `"boolean"`. If you add `as const` to the end of the object literal [like this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBARgVylcAFATiADhGBeGAbwCgYyYwBDAWwFMAuIgawEswATegImnTYHMuAGhi1qWKAE96AM0oAbCLQC+Q0uQAWtFvw1RGhVh25gE1OLXTCY1NvQBMABhHVKAD3oBWR6vVkA7izsUBoGRpxcpuaW1rZg9AAcPmrkMOyU6ExhbBFwICDytJRgXMrEyjCUuKCQUADcQA):

```
const buttonProps = {
    // ...
} as const;
```

...you're telling TypeScript the object is immutable, and it will infer the string literal types instead. Then we can go about building a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#handbook-content) to infer the type you want from `buttonProps`:

```typescript
// A property type in button props
type PropertyEntry = {
    kind: "string" | "number" | "boolean";
    empty?: boolean;
};

// The type for a property (ignoring `empty`, we'll handle that separately)
type PropertyValueType<T extends PropertyEntry> =
    T extends {kind: "string"}
    ? string
    : T extends {kind: "number"}
    ? number
    : T extends {kind: "boolean"}
    ? boolean
    : never;

// The mapped type that accepts the type of an object using `PropertyEntry`
// elements and provides the type that object describes
type PropertiesType<ObjectType extends Record<string, PropertyEntry>> =
    // The non-optional ones (no `empty` or `empty: false`):
    & {
        -readonly [Key in keyof ObjectType as ObjectType[Key] extends {empty: true} ? never : Key]: PropertyValueType<ObjectType[Key]>;
    }
    // The optional ones (`empty: true`):
    & {
        -readonly [Key in keyof ObjectType as ObjectType[Key] extends {empty: true} ? Key : never]?: PropertyValueType<ObjectType[Key]>;
    };
```

There I'm using various [mapping modifiers](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#mapping-modifiers) and handling the optional properties (`empty: true`) separately from the non-optional ones (so I can apply the optional modifier `?` to the optional ones).

Using it with `buttonProps`:

```typescript
// Testing with `buttonProps` from the question
const buttonProps = {
    name: {kind:"string", empty:false},
    height: {kind:"number", min:20, max:50},
    width: {kind:"number", min:80},
    dark: {kind:"boolean"},
    optionalBool: {kind: "boolean", empty: true} // Added this for testing
} as const;

type ButtonProps = PropertiesType<typeof buttonProps>;
//   ^? type ButtonProps = { name: string, height: number, width: number, dark: boolean} & { optionalBool?: boolean | undefined }

// Test the type
const x: ButtonProps = {
    dark: true,
    name: "x",
    height: 0,
    width: 0,
    // Optional prop not required
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEEFQBwJweygUxgFwJ6nU0BLAdqAEYCuKKcBsCAzgFBaKgAK8SqaAonijBgLygA3rVCjQAa3wATAFygARNR74A5vNAAfBXmIBbQsnVb5hOHAA2iAIZ55AbhFjEuqOgD8c0xet4HAXwdaEFAAFQALRgZQADM4GFAraFZkdFAAChwVPDjVUAADZ1c0PIAaUAB3RAByc3NQMJspS0wGlFBqRCgrGCsURHM0AEp6NGwWBBS0ADUrc2JEENHEAB4Q0EQADz68KWpmZPYuHjQAPlA+R1E1ze3doUkduUVlPDU-S9A3dpeVD7lrraIHZ7QQPWTaPQGGDyd5iT6gHT6ZB-ULrQHA+7SJ5eSw2GEfL44nwovCIABuyECwXCjF0VigSCkmCWLV6CQAxuzOig9igIszsHBogkCHBCAArRDstrEai5PLjNjoI68PJBMD9ZxAnkiplUMk4KSIXn8qJ8tliyXS0BG6jsmA4Ax0KKKlI4Y2LJDLADyEqlKE9jBuQLuACUpXEpMslA7XmVXYduLwTmcLnDqfzsngALQIFA4CizUAUY3pbL5QroPLF+IFFzoOTRWYdPKDGQfABkQg+cOzMGsUgoA1AAG0ANKIDD4CSToWgX1WgMsqx7Bf+wPjycAXTRtxBlbQch48z88NJFPicgnaC3cgT6BmcwWSx9fulG+vW5ODjhsLEGcYPMCzwIsSz2NI6yKI8YHmVt2zhLthDhXt+ysQc8GHTcpwIcRZ2FNd32XVc3yXJAsJ3YMMUEA9oJPeFr1AORz2QLcPH2CZ2EfeZA1fRcP23b8PgCWh1VCY181eCocD5fISDIChFWoatongXQWkYABHeYlGA2h2QoJQiFIcg8EU85uzhEDdEQORQSxZ5YzUMoaKbcwOj8EoPgiTIwhQWywRkeRESheQyl0fAZAAJgABjCqwNhkABWaKPI+cpDT5fz7OCwwwoigAOFLPLhKRunELLHhMMxcVsVK4SAwtzAAIWqirwSq7w8Wc+tD0wGDEFPYJwCkI0mT5HA9lieI+h015aFPFdQH0vAlECKImuMhTWD2AR73dageIYOc5JMxTBOCUQAD03BE6lxPUgVED0gy2gS0ANvk0ztvMpCxFKmByr6+ZirEKybIUDZQq8xAfL80BYrSjKwjkBH0zAb1XGAosqCgBE4DafstJwfspHmuwgA)

Plenty to tweak in there I'm sure (and it wouldn't surprise me if it can be done more succinctly), but that's the main idea.

Comment: I was almost there! I didn't use `as const` though I did think about it when writing the question... Thanks!

Comment: // Union type representing the mapping from type strings to TypeScript types
      type TypeMap =
        | { type: "number"; tsType: number }
        | { type: "string"; tsType: string };

      // Mapped type to transform the structure
      type Params = {
        [K in keyof typeof params]: Extract<
          TypeMap,
          { type: (typeof params)[K]["kind"] }
        >["tsType"];
      };

Comment: Thanks, but it returns readonly. I'll look at the above and fix that. Thanks again!